# windows batch, interate/tokenize a string, without delimitators

Tags: string, batch-file, cmd

how can I get this result in a bat file?

```
C:\> script.bat 1a23
single char: 1
single char: a
single char: 2
single char: 3
C:\>
```

i tried the `FOR` command but it always require a delimiter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL
SET var=%1
:loop
IF DEFINED var ECHO single char: %var:~0,1%&SET var=%var:~1%&GOTO loop
GOTO :EOF
```

should do as you've asked.

Answer (score 1):

This approximates your aim - the best way to do it depends on what you actually need to do.

```
set "var=%~1"
set "char=%var:~0,1%"
echo(%char%
set "char=%var:~1,1%"
echo(%char%
set "char=%var:~2,1%"
echo(%char%
set "char=%var:~3,1%"
echo(%char%
```